Laravel validate index array of object
Is there anyway to validate the index array of objects in laravel with the validator?
Here is my post data:
[
    {
        "order_id": 601696,
        "is_delay": 0,
        "ship_date": null,
        "times": 1,
        "warehouse_id": 237,
        "ship_type": 1,
        "package": [
            {
                "sku": "JD-XL102",
                "order_item_id": 772447,
                "qty": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "order_id": 601696,
        "is_delay": 0,
        "ship_date": null,
        "times": 1,
        "warehouse_id": 251,
        "ship_type": 1,
        "package": [
            {
                "sku": "JD-D16",
                "order_item_id": 772447,
                "qty": 1
            },
            {
                "sku": "JD-D16-GC",
                "order_item_id": 772448,
                "qty": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]

Then i want to validate it like this :
public function rules()
{
    return [
        '*.*.order_id'      => 'required|integer',
        '*.*.is_delay'      => 'required|boolean',
        '*.*.ship_date'     => 'nullable|datetime',
        '*.*.times'         => 'required|integer|min:1',
        '*.*.warehouse_id'  => 'required|integer',
        '*.*.ship_type'     => 'required|integer',
        '*.*.package'       => 'required|array',
        '*.*.package.*.sku' => 'required|string',
        '*.*.package.*.qty' => 'required|integer|min:1',
    ];
}

Howevere it not works.
I know i can add a prefix field to fix it, but i just want to know if laravel support the index array to validate without the prefix key?
{
    "rows": [
        {...}
    ]
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'row'                 => 'required|array',
        'row.*.order_id'      => 'required|integer',
        'row.*.is_delay'      => 'required|boolean',
        'row.*.ship_date'     => 'nullable|datetime',
        'row.*.times'         => 'required|integer|min:1',
        'row.*.warehouse_id'  => 'required|integer',
        'row.*.ship_type'     => 'required|integer',
        'row.*.package'       => 'required|array',
        'row.*.package.*.sku' => 'required|string',
        'row.*.package.*.qty' => 'required|integer|min:1',
    ];
}

PHP version: v7.4.33
Laravel version: v6.20.44

Instead of this '*.*.order_id'=> 'required|integer', try this '*.order_id' =>'required|integer',.In this way remove the the first * from validation rule and try again.

Unfortunately, with Laravel’s validation rules, you can’t validate an array without a key (like your example). Laravel needs a wrapper key (u name it a prefix) to know how to apply the rules.
So, you have to either wrap your array with a key (e.g., row) before validating it or handle it manually using loops like this (But it's not the best option ):
$data = $request->all(); // Assume this is the incoming data
$errors = [];

foreach ($data as $index => $item) {
    $validator = Validator::make($item, [
        'order_id'      => 'required|integer',
        'is_delay'      => 'required|boolean',
        'ship_date'     => 'nullable|date',
        'times'         => 'required|integer|min:1',
        'warehouse_id'  => 'required|integer',
        'ship_type'     => 'required|integer',
        'package'       => 'required|array',
        'package.*.sku' => 'required|string',
        'package.*.qty' => 'required|integer|min:1',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errors[$index] = $validator->errors()->toArray();
    }
}

if (!empty($errors)) {
    return response()->json(['errors' => $errors], 422);
}

